# Flutter / Dart equivalent for "ChaChaPoly.SealedBox" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, cryptography

I am developing a flutter application and need a equivalent to the "ChaChaPoly.SealedBox" in Swift (Cryptokit). Its important to initialize the box with a combination of nonce and cipher text. We do not have the nonce as separated bytes.

In Swift it looks like:

```
    let encryptedBytes : Data = Data(base64Encoded: serverResponse)

    let sealedBox = try! ChaChaPoly.SealedBox(combined: encryptedBytes)

    let symmKey : SymmetricKey = SymmetricKey(data: keyData)

    let decodedData : Data = try! ChaChaPoly.open(sealedBox, using: symmKey)
```

How could this be solved using flutter?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography Take a look at this package